# Highlight cell on condition

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I'm trying to highlight all cells that are before the current date. However I am highlighting all cells instead of just the old dates.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime 

#get file 
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\cc-621.xlsx')
df

# sort the data by date 
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Expiration Date'])
df = df.sort_values(by='Expiration Date')
df = df.reset_index()
df

# sort by todays date 
today = datetime.now(tz=None)
today

def expired(self):
    for index, rows in df.iterrows():
        color = 'red' if rows['Expiration Date'] < today else 'green'
        return 'background-color: %s' %color

new = df.style.applymap(expired)
new
```

Comment: also tried with `df.style.apply(expired,axis=None)` ? also change `df.iterrows()` to `self.iterrows()` (though you should look for a vectorized way and not using iterrows) in the function but to test you have to provide a data

Comment: No still not working

Comment: Why don't you try to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is create new DataFrame filled by styles by condition with [`Styler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html), for set rows by conditions is used [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
def expired(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: red'
    c2 = 'background-color: green'

    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    m = x['Expiration Date'] < today
    df1['Expiration Date'] = np.where(m, c1, c2)
    return df1

df.style.apply(expired, axis=None)
```

If coloring all rows by condition use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
def expired(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: red'
    c2 = 'background-color: green'

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(c1, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    m = x['Expiration Date'] < today
    df1 = df1.mask(m, c2)
    return df1
```

Comment: `rng = pd.date_range('2019-09-25', periods=10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Expiration Date': rng, 'a': range(10)})` with `df.style.apply(expired, axis=None).to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False)`

Answer (score 2):

`applymap` is executed on each cell. You don't need to loop over each row if using this. However, it seems you are trying to highlight the entire row, so you likely want `apply` by row. Using this method, you have to return an array with the same size as each row.

```
def expired(val):
    return ['background-color: green' if val['Expiration Date'] else ''] * len(val)

new = df.style.apply(expired, axis=1)
```